# How do i reduce the following code to one line in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How do i reduce the following code to one line in Ruby?

```
unless(current_facebook_user.nil?)
    unless(current_facebook_user.client.nil?)
        unless(current_facebook_user.client.default_params.nil?)
            val = current_facebook_user.client.default_params
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can using the `try()` method from `active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb` introduced since [Rails 2.3.2](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.2/Object/try)

```
val = current_facebook_user.try(:client).try(:default_params)
```

[Method Try](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try)

Or directly using **Safe navigation operator** introduced since [Ruby 2.3.0](https://www.ruby-lang.org/fr/news/2015/12/25/ruby-2-3-0-released/)

```
val = current_facebook_user&.client&.default_params
```

documented [here](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11537)

[more on Safe navigation operator](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/)

Comment: I think I prefer this to my solution! :-)

Comment: @joel : Great job, It is beautiful. But do u know how we do this in ruby rather than rails

Comment: @Sreeaj: watch the documentation linked in answer. you'll see how that method is implemented (1 line of code). so you can use it in your non-rails projects/classes ;)

Comment: @Andrea : Thanks for your comment. That we need to use the send function manuall.. I was searching an inbuilt function in ruby. No probs I am happy with Joel's answer..

Answer (score 1):

Use `||` operator in one `unless`: `val = ... unless cond1 || cond2 || cond3`

Or use `&&` on negations of the conditions in `if`: `val = ... if !cond1 && !cond2`

Answer (score 0):

You may not need the third check, as if .default_params is nil, val will be evaluated nil too (if it started nil, this is no problem; if it was already populated, you might want to keep the third guard there :-)

```
val = current_facebook_user.client.default_params if current_facebook_user && current_facebook_user.client && current_facebook_user.client.default_params
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val = current_facebook_user.client.default_params unless current_facebook_user.nil? or current_facebook_user.client.nil? or current_facebook_user.client.default_params.nil?
```